# Why is this tab opening on startup, and how do I prevent it from happening again?

Tags: windows, firefox, browser-tabs, session-restore, discord

I have Firefox set up so that on startup, it opens with the browsing tabs from the previous sessions restored.  This is desired behaviour, so I don't want to change that.

The issue I'm having is that for the past week or so, there is always an extra tab when Firefox opens, always for the same site.  It's an article about the League of Legends finals, if that is relevant. ([link](https://nexus.leagueoflegends.com/en-us/2019/10/10-thoughts-going-into-semifinals/))

This is annoying me, because this isn't a page I actually visited on purpose.  I believe I clicked it from the homepage of Discord accidentally.  Thinking it may be Discord opening the page on startup, first I "unfollowed" every game on Discord.  That did not change anything that I could tell.  Uninstalling Discord did not make the problem go away either.

**Why is this tab opening on startup, and how do I prevent it from happening again?**

I don't know if there's some way to diagnose these things on Firefox, or if this issue is fairly common with a known solution, but any constructive input is appreciated.

I've been having a hard time concisely wording this issue, so searching online for solutions hasn't been helpful at all.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the _Mozilla_ _Firefox_ Web-Browser?

Comment: What browser extensions do you have installed?

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai Uninstalling a browser could be both unnecessary and insufficient. Modern browsers keep their profiles neatly separated from program files. If you want to start over, you can simply delete the profile. Meanwhile, uninstalling the browser may not remove the profile.

Comment: @gronostaj Reddit enchancement suite, To Google Translate, uBlock Origin and WOT Web of Trust.  As far as reinstalling Firefox goes, I don't know if that would mess with my history and stuff.  I'd also rather have a solution that actually addresses the cause, if possible.

Comment: Try to disable all browser extensions and see if the problem persists. If it doesn't, enable them one by one trying again after each one.